# Элемент не выравнивается по горизонтали | css

Tags: html, css

Изображение должно размещаться на 65px от верха странички и в центре по горизонтали. Высота регулируется корректно, а центрирование не работает. Что не так?

html-код:

```
<img id="screen" width="640" height="480" src="">
```

css-код:

```
#screen {
        margin: 65px auto;
        background: #eee;
        border: black;
    }
```

Comment: можете попробовать написать `display: block` для изображения

Comment: да, это помогло + я кое-что убрал (ибо раньше не помогало), и теперь все ровно, спасибо

Comment: @BERTOLDO, как там транслирующий видео сервер? Потом покажешь?

Comment: могу скинуть код сервера, если надо

Answer (score 0):

Оберни img в div и все будет работать)

```css
#screen {
    margin-top: 65px;
    background: #eee;
    border: black;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="screen" width="640" height="480" src="">
</div>
```